# Flex 3: Setting one arrayCollection to another is stalling the application

Tags: apache-flex, arraycollection

I'll just go ahead and C/P the entire function to ensure you guys see everything going on:

```
public function directorsPrepsToShow():void
{
    var tempDPrepsAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;
    var dprepSD:Date = new Date;
    var dprepED:Date = new Date;
    var viewSD:Date = rightDate(startViewDate.getMonth(), startViewDate.getDate(), startViewDate.getFullYear());
    var viewED:Date = rightDate(viewSD.getMonth(), viewSD.getDate() + 14, viewSD.getFullYear());
    var newACIDs:String = new String;
    var useACIDs:String = new String;

    for each (var item:Object in dPrepAC)
    {
            dprepSD = textToDate(item[2]);
            dprepED = rightDate(dprepSD.getMonth(), Number(dprepSD.getDate() + (item[3] - 1)), dprepSD.getFullYear());

            if (dateCollider(dprepSD, dprepED, viewSD, viewED))
                    tempDPrepsAC.addItem(item as Array);
    }

    if (tempDPrepsAC.length != usePrepAC.length)
    {
            usePrepAC = new ArrayCollection();
            usePrepAC = tempDPrepsAC;
            Alert.show("HI");
    }
}
```

This function is in a separate file, that's called from the main mxml via the following:

```
<mx:Script source="functions/dprep.as" />
```

The line that's causing the app to stall is "usePrepAC = tempDPrepAC;".  usePrepAC is declared in the main mxml like this:

```
[Bindable] public var usePrepAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;
```

Dose anybody see why this one line would cause the application to stall?  If I comment out that line, the application loads fine (loads everything except for the information that this AC should contain).  I've been looking at this now for about an hour, trying different ways to get the contents of tempDPrepsAC into usePrepAC - but nothing is working.  I tried googling it, but found nothing :(

Thanks,
Brds

**EDIT**

dprep AC is declared in the main mxml like this:

```
[Bindable] public var dPrepAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;
```

And the function that populates it is as follows:

```
public function createDirectorsPrepCollection(e:ResultEvent):void
{
    var xmlList:XMLList = XML(e.result).directorsprep;
    var dupString:String = "|";
    var tempArray:Array = new Array;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < xmlList.length(); i++)
    {
        if (dupString.indexOf(String("|" + xmlList[i].name.@id) + "|") == -1)
        {
            tempArray = new Array;
            tempArray[0] = xmlList[i].prepDBID;
            tempArray[1] = xmlList[i].projectDBID;
            tempArray[2] = xmlList[i].startdate;
            tempArray[3] = xmlList[i].numdays;
            tempArray[4] = xmlList[i].positions;

            dPrepAC.addItem(tempArray);

            dupString += "|" + xmlList[i].prepDBID + "|";
        }
    }

    directorsPrepsToShow();
}
```

This function is called by this:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="dprepHttp" url="{dprepXML}" resultFormat="e4x" makeObjectsBindable="true" result="createDirectorsPrepCollection(event)" />
```

dPrepAC is populating fine btw... I check it in a for each loop.

Comment: Does it ever come back; or does it just hang forever?  Are you running in debug mode?  Are you sure a breakpoint hasn't fired and is waiting for you to continue?  There should be no reason an assignment like that should cause the app to hang.

Comment: No, i left it running overnight... so 15 hours, and it still didn't load.  I've read up about cloning AC's and from what i've read, when you do something like "ac1 = ac2" then they share the memory location, which can really mess things up.  Everybody says they have a solution, but none of them seem to be working.  The debug console simply showed: "CGS.swf - 1,440,595 bytes after decompression" after running

Comment: I agree with Flextras, I don't see any reason why that would cause your app to hang. Are you sure it's getting to that line? Perhaps `tempDPrepsAC.length == usePrepAC.length` so that line was never called?

Comment: Hmmm, I've changed up the function for testing purposes.  Instead of populating a temp AC and then comparing it to the main one, I've just repopulated the main one every single time.  So pretty much, the if statement within the for each loop reads like this: "if (dateCollider(dprepSD, dprepED, viewSD, viewED)) usePrepAC.addItem(item as Array);"  After this, it still stalls.

Comment: @Jason Towne - if i comment that line out, the app loads

Comment: @Brds Where is `DPrepAC` declared/created?

Comment: @Jason Towne - i added the information to the EDIT part of my post

Comment: This is the point where I'd like to ask for a full runnable sample that replicates the problem.

Comment: @Flextras... Hmmm, I made a new project, included only the stuff that was causing a problem, and it worked.  I kinda wish it didn't so that you guys could take a look at it and hopefully help solve the problem, but i'll have to go through all my code and see if i can figure out what the deal is.

Comment: I'd love to run it and debug it too, its got to be something simple going haywire :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code:

```
usePrepAC.source = tempDPrepsAC.source;
```

Comment: I am sure its big XML parsing that is giving this hanging effect. Can you try limiting all your for loops to 3-4 items and then trying your code as it is.

Comment: There's only 2 items in the XML file.